# Qual a etimologia da gíria brasileira "paga pau"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, girias

No Brasil existe uma gíria "paga pau" e expressões correlatas "pagar pau", "pagou pau", etc.

Uma busca rápida por significados nos trás:

> - [[1]](http://significado.ws/paga-pau) Paga Pau pode ser uma pessoa que faz tudo que outra quer, seja por medo, respeito ou admiração.
> - [[2]](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/paga+pau/) Aquele que gosta de puxar saco, adular outras pessoas com intenção de conseguir algum benefício.
> - [[3]](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111008093148AAfqxNI)  Paga-pau é aquele tipo de pessoa que fala mal de outra, mas copia ela, que tem inveja dela entende.
>     Tipo, eu vou lá e compro um carro novo, dai vem você, que só me critica, e compra um igual, você estaria pagando-pau de mim;

Qual a etimologia desta expressão?

Comment: Aqui em Portugal diz-se "ser um pau mandado" de alguém que anda a mando de outro, aparentemente sem vontade própria; que parece ser a mesma coisa que o primeiro significado que listas. Às tantas há alguma relação.

Comment: Acho melhor falar em origem e não etimologia....

Answer (score 3):

Em meados de 80 já existia.

Não posso garantir que surgiu na década de 80, pode ter surgido antes. Mas me lembro quando essa e outras gírias passaram a ser usadas nas ruas de São Paulo, durante minha infância e adolescência. Eu acredito que não existia antes. Mas pelo menos, sabemos que se difundiu nos anos 80.

**Definição de "Paga pau" como a ouvíamos nas ruas**:

Alguém tão encantado com alguém, ao ponto de presentear ou dar **coisas/valores (dinheiro)** para a pessoa admirada.

**Pau como sinônimo de dinheiro**

A palavra "pau" foi e ainda é usada como um dos sinônimos para dinheiro (no singular mesmo - linguagem coloquial e das ruas):

- Quantos **pau** você pagou naquela casa ?
- Paguei 45 **pau** nesse carro *(a grandeza é deduzida do contexto podendo ser milhares, milhões, bilhões, etc)*
- Você me deve 5 **pau**
- Sobrou 2 **pau** de troco

**Pau como pontos**:

A título e curiosidade, em outras situações "pau" também pode se referir a pontos, ou crédito sobre algo. Não sei se daqui é que vem o uso como sinônimo de dinheiro, ou é apenas coincidência, mas como exemplo no [Jogo de Truco](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truco_paulista) os pontos são comumente chamados de "pau":

- Nessa rodada já estamos com 4 **pau**
- Ao desafiar o adversário com o aumento de pontos de uma rodada: "Truco ! Três **pau** ! Três **pau** !"
- Ou a revidada na resposta ao grito do truco: "Seis **pau** ladrão !"

Answer (score 0):

Originária no Rio de janeiro na década de 80, Paga Pau pode ser uma pessoa que faz tudo que outra quer, seja por medo, respeito ou admiração.

Answer (score 0):

No Brasil, quando dizemos que alguém "paga pau" significa que está querendo ter algo com alguém.
Por exemplo, você está na rua e alguém diz "aquele(a) rapaz/mulher está pagando pau pra você". Significa que ele(a) está gostando muito do que está vendo, geralmente apenas de forma física, mas se ele(a) também "assistir" alguma atitude da pessoa, também pode gostar e "pagar pau".

Comment: Olá Julia, bem-vind ao site. Você explicou o significado da palavra, mas a pergunta é sobre a etimologia (isto é, a origem dela).

Comment: Aqui no Brasil, houve uma época - ainda tem gente que usa o termo - para dinheiro. Por exemplo: um produto de R$ 50,00 era dito são 50 paus. Então, o "paga pau" seria porque a pessoa "gostava" da outra a ponto de pagar. Não tem a ver com prostitutas porque poderia ser qualquer pessoa. Mas, como disse, o "paga pau" veio do termo associado ao dinheiro.

Answer (score 0):

Vem de: 'paga para levar pau' levar pau na gíria da escola dos anos 70, era ser reprovado - não passa de ano. Depois isso evoluiu para ' pagar pau' é algo como: Se lascar pelos outros, guentar pau.

Answer (score -2):

*Paga pau:* Significa uma pessoa que baba, idolatra alguém/algo.

> Tu gostas de pagar pau pra esse Mc Livinho, né? Dê a sua para ele, já que ama tanto ele!
>
> Tu és um paga pau desse Michael Jackson, né?
>
> Pare de defender o seu amigo, você sabe que ele está errado, seu paga pau!

Comment: Desculpas, amigo, mas eu não preciso da definição, os dicionarios ligados na pergunta já o fazem. Quero a origem da expressão.

Comment: Amigo, não há origens para gírias brasileiras, isso não é Ingles. Gírias brasileiras surgem a cada 5 minutos em todos os lugares do Brasil, seja no Sul, Norte, Nordeste ou Oeste. Você nunca irá achar a origem desses tipos de gírias e expressões. Claro que existem locais de origens de certas gírias e expressôes, como por exemplo: Oxente - Nordeste. Trem, fita (usado para quase tudo) - Minas Gerais, Se aprochegue meu rei - Bahia. Pelo seu nome e seu jeito de falar, eu presumo que você não seja nativo, então aqui vai a minha dica:

Comment: @DavydDiniz "não tente encontrar" é um comentário totalmente desnecessário para um site de questionamentos. O questionamento original é sobre etimologia e de oxente por exemplo é ser proveniente de "ó gente", que tem um uso comum na região nordeste. OP: Se pesquisar mais a fundo vai achar de "paga-pau" sim, a expressão se popularizou com a música de Fernando e Sorocaba. A expressão "puxa-saco" vem de gíria militar: "De modo submisso, carregavam os sacos de roupas dos oficiais em viagem". Se for algum tipo de pesquisa mais séria eu pesquisaria em algo próximo a isso.

Comment: @EdgarRochaCarvalho E onde você encontrou isso? Qual fonte? Você simplesmente viu na internet? Gírias em Brasil são constantes, não há como saber a origem, ninguém realmente sabe se essa gíria veio mesmo dai, ela poderia ter existido há muito tempo atrás ou sido popularizada de outras regiões. Fernando e Sorocaba, uma dupla sertaneja, provavelmente seu sucesso é recente, e como pode essa expressão que já existe há muito tempo surgir de uma dupla sertaneja? É melhor não tentar encontrar, do que sair com a informação errada

Comment: @DavydDiniz Eu não disse que a origem veio deles, eu disse que se popularizou com eles. Forneci apenas um caminho de uma etimologia próxima para uma linha de pesquisa. O exemplo que peguei foi do livro Manual de Etimologia Português. Livros de etimologia são comumente usados como referência bibliográfica de estudantes de filosofia, além das áreas óbvias que fazem uso deste assunto. Continuo discordando de você, há sim como saber a origem e existem pesquisadores sérios que se dedicam quase exclusivamente a isso.

Comment: @EdgarRochaCarvalho Entendo seu ponto de vista, mas não temos como saber quem foi a primeira quem passou o vírus da gripe adiante, do mesmo jeito que o nordeste passou a utilizar a expressão "oxente" com mais frequência, mas isso não quer dizer que essa expressão surgiu de lá, pode ter vindo de outros estados. Então, não acho que seja possível saber exatamente de onde veio, e sim quais estados e lugares as usam com mais frequência. Aliás, não acho que o fórum deveria aceitar questões como essas, esse fórum é relacionado à questões sobre a língua portuguesa, e não sobre história.

Comment: @DavydDiniz Desculpe mas tem uma relação direta com o estudo de um determinado idioma e sua compreensão. Este livro é justamente sobre técnicas relacionadas a pesquisa correta da etimologia e há sim como saber. Na verdade até acrescento que Estados e lugares que usam com frequência não é o que mais importa nesse estudo. Não é o caso da gripe, mas assim como a etimologia, existe a linha de pesquisa em buscar o primeiro a passar um vírus a diante, os termos são "index case" ou "paciente zero". Nem tudo é tão caótico como está supondo... em ambos casos existem estudos sérios na busca da origem.

Comment: @DavydDiniz vale sempre a pena pesquisar, mas há que saber fazê-lo. Eu mesmo já encontrei algumas possíveis origens de algumas expressões e/ou palavras. As vezes não dá para saber qual a real origem, mas dá para chegar muito perto ou pelo menos ter uma ideia se há ou não um origem ou possíveis origens. De qualquer forma vale sempre a pena pesquisar, seja sobre que assunto for.